# why config folder is not pushed?

Tags: git, deployment, heroku

Although I am sure that I've added& committed ALL files and folders into my local git repo before push

I don't know why the remote repo is missing the config folder

I don't know how to investigate this problem, of course I didn't add the config folder name to the .gitignore or .slugignore , but, its never get pushed!

I did `git init`, git `add .`, `git commit`, then

```
git push heroku master
```

So, and idea about this issue ?

EDIT

When I try to add files in config manually, I get:

```
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ cd config
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ git add *
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ git commit -m "config files"
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$
```

EDIT 2

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global

# Ignore bundler config


# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3



# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ ls config/
application.rb  boot.rb  database.yml  environment.rb  environments  initializers  locales  newrelic.yml  routes.rb
```

EDIT 3

```
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ ls config
application.rb  database.yml    environments  locales       routes.rb
boot.rb         environment.rb  initializers  newrelic.yml
```

EDIT 4

```
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ cd config
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ echo 'test' > test_file
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ ls config
ls: cannot access config: No such file or directory
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ dir
application.rb  database.yml    environments  locales       routes.rb
boot.rb     environment.rb  initializers  newrelic.yml  test_file
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   test_file
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ git add .
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ git commit -m "a file"
[master 55a0159] a file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 config/test_file
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 336 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rack app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.rc
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Using rake (0.9.2.2)
       Using i18n (0.6.0)
       Using multi_json (1.3.4)
       Using activesupport (3.2.3)
       Using builder (3.0.0)
       Using activemodel (3.2.3)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using journey (1.0.3)
       Using rack (1.4.1)
       Using rack-cache (1.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.1)
       Using hike (1.2.1)
       Using tilt (1.3.3)
       Using sprockets (2.1.3)
       Using actionpack (3.2.3)
       Using mime-types (1.18)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.10)
       Using mail (2.4.4)
       Using actionmailer (3.2.3)
       Using arel (3.0.2)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
       Using activerecord (3.2.3)
       Using activeresource (3.2.3)
       Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
       Using cancan (1.6.7)
       Using cocoon (1.0.20)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.3.1)
       Using execjs (1.3.2)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
       Using json (1.7.1)
       Using rdoc (3.12)
       Using thor (0.14.6)
       Using railties (3.2.3)
       Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Using commonjs (0.2.6)
       Using daemons (1.1.8)
       Using orm_adapter (0.0.7)
       Using warden (1.1.1)
       Using devise (2.0.4)
       Using eventmachine (0.12.10)
       Using google-analytics-rails (0.0.2)
       Using haml (3.1.4)
       Using jquery-rails (2.0.2)
       Using jquery-rails-cdn (0.1.0)
       Using json_pure (1.6.6)
       Using less (2.2.1)
       Using less-rails (2.2.3)
       Using libv8 (3.3.10.4)
       Using on_the_spot (1.0.0)
       Using pg (0.13.2)
       Using bundler (1.2.0.rc)
       Using rails (3.2.3)
       Using routing-filter (0.3.0)
       Using sass (3.1.17)
       Using sass-rails (3.2.5)
       Using simple_form (2.0.1)
       Using therubyracer (0.10.1)
       Using thin (1.3.1)
       Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.1.0) from git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git (at master)
       Using uglifier (1.2.4)
       Using validate_url (0.2.0)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rack -> console, rake, web
-----> Compiled slug size is 18.7MB
-----> Launching... done, v20
       http://dcaclab3.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:dcaclab3.git
   f434d33..55a0159  master -> master
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/config$ heroku run bash -a dcaclab3
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.1
~ $ dir
app  config.ru  doc  Gemfile.lock  public    README.rdoc  test
bin  db     Gemfile  lib           Rakefile  script       vendor
```

EDIT 5

To make sure that the problem in the push, and that my local commit works fine:

```
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ git ls-files config/
config/application.rb
config/boot.rb
config/database.yml
config/environment.rb
config/environments/development.rb
config/environments/production.rb
config/environments/test.rb
config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
config/initializers/devise.rb
config/initializers/inflections.rb
config/initializers/mail.rb
config/initializers/mime_types.rb
config/initializers/secret_token.rb
config/initializers/session_store.rb
config/initializers/simple_form.rb
config/initializers/task_scheduler.rb
config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
config/locales/ar.yml
config/locales/devise.en.yml
config/locales/en.yml
config/locales/simple_form.en.yml
config/newrelic.yml
config/routes.rb
config/test_file
```

EDIT 6

To make sure that there is no other .gitignore is lurking

```
sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ ~/.gitignore
bash: /home/sam/.gitignore: No such file or directory

sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ find ~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab -name ".gitignore"
/home/sam/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/.gitignore
```

1. Patterns read from $GIT_DIR/info/exclude.

   sam@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab$ cat ~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/.git/exclude
   cat: /home/sam/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/.git/exclude: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you mean `.git/config` or a non-empty directory called 'config'?

Comment: its a non-empty directory called 'config'

Comment: What do `cat .gitignore` and `ls config/` tell you? (as per @umlaeute's response)

Comment: cat .gitignore dose not show any thing related to config folder, as for ls config/ please see above in EDIT

Comment: about EDIT5: you are doing `cat ~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/.git/exclude` when you really should be doing `cat ~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/.git/info/exclude`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have contacted heroku, we discovered that removing the file .slugignore which is beside file .gitignore fixed the problem!

So, it was a bug at heroku side, sadly that was the reason, thanks for every body who tried to help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 empty directories

git will not check-in an empty directory, so if your "config" dir is empty, it will not be included into your commit. "fix" that by adding a dummy-file

```
touch config/nada
git add config/nada
git commit config/nada -m "dummy file to force inclusion of config/"
git push heroku master
```

## 2 gitignore

probably the files in your config/ directory are in some global or system-wide .gitignore file

*EDIT1:*

there are a number of ways how you can specify files excluded by git. you might want to check all of them to see whether you are ignoring your config-directory:

- command-line args (probably not your problem)
- .gitignore file in the git repository directories
- $GIT_DIR/info/exclude
- a file specified by the core.excludes property (either system wide or global)

  `git config core.excludes`

  `git config --global core.excludes`

  `git config --system core.excludes`

check all the possibilities, eventually posting them here (or at some pastebin)

in any case, you should be able to override excludes by explicitely adding a file:

```
git add config/foo.conf
git commit config/foo.conf -m "manually added foo.conf"
git push heroku master
```

*EDIT2:*

## 3 pushing...

i don't think that "pushing" is the problem, but rather adding the files to the repository.
confirm, that the config-files are indeed under git-control.
e.g. after adding/committing your files do:

```
git ls-files config/
```

and make sure that the files are there.

*EDIT3:*

additionally, it might well be that you are pushing correctly to heroku, but they are not synching your repo as expected to the deployment, so the remote-console does not show the config (either because it's excluded from the sync, because it ends up somewhere else or because it's filtered out when displaying it; or because you are actually looking at the wrong place)

so do:

```
$ git add config/foo.conf
$ git commit config/foo.conf -m "manually added foo.conf"
$ git push heroku master

$ cd /tmp
$ git clone <remote-url-for-heroku> testclone
$ ls testclone/config/
```

if this works, then something is wrong with the checkout on the heroku-site.
mabe you need to do something like this:

```
$ heroku run bash -a dcaclab3
[...]
$$ git pull
$$ ls config/
```

Comment: no, its not empty directory, as for adding the config directory please see edit above

Comment: try to explicitely add your files with "git add config/file" rather than implictely with "git add ."

Comment: see my EDIT1 in the answer for various ways to exclude files (ala .gitignore)

Comment: actually, what makes you think that it is the "push" that fails, rather than the "commit"? all answers try to solve a "commit" problem (and i agree), but you ought to make sure...see EDIT2

Comment: I've checked your EDIT 2, please see my EDIT 5, the config folder is under git-control

Comment: please also do an `ls ~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab` on your local machine...maybe you are simply checking the wrong (remote) place?

Comment: Thanks very much, but, it was a bug at Heroku! config folder is pushed after I removed .slugignore file!

Comment: please add your solution as an "answer" to your question and accept it, so people know that the problem is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a limited number of places git looks for ignored files. Let's check all of them (paraphrased from `man gitignore`):

```
1.   Patterns read from the command line for those commands that support them.

2.   Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to
     the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These patterns match
     relative to the location of the .gitignore file. A project normally includes such .gitignore files in its repository, containing patterns for files
     generated as part of the project build.

3.   Patterns read from $GIT_DIR/info/exclude.

4.   Patterns read from the file specified by the configuration variable core.excludesfile.
```

It's not `1`. You're using porcelain commands that don't support CLI excludes. It could still be `2` based on your current edits. What is in `~/.gitignore`, and issue `find ~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab -name ".gitignore"` to confirm you've got no other ones lurking. To test `3`, issue `cat ~/RubymineProjects/dcaclab/.git/exclude`. To test `4`, issue `git config core.excludefile` and `git config --global core.excludefile` and edit in the output.

Comment: I am not sure about point 4, I issued git config core.excludefile and git config --global core.excludefile , but, no output there, can you please explain this point ?

Comment: If you see no output, it means those variables weren't set, so the only one I see left that isn't in your edits is number 3. Did you try that one? I might have missed it.